# css response div background image strectchs and scales on browser sizes

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to have a div element which stretches across the page that is a certain height for the image and that image scales to the div element and when you resize the browser the image adjusts to fit the best example is microsoft's windows 8.1 website have a look at the image that scales when in different browser sizes. [microsoft link here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/home)

Comment: `background-size: cover` or `contain` it you want to maintain proportions?

Answer (score 1):

In your style sheet:

```
.your_element {
     width:100%;
     padding:0 0 36% 0;
     background:url(pic.jpg) no-repeat top;
     background-size:100% auto;
}
```

..and your HTML...

```
<div class="your_element">
</div>
```

You'll need to adjust the percentage in the padding to suit.

Comment: What's the padding for?

Comment: @savidpauljunior You need height on the element or you won't see it. The padding gives you that. Change the value until you get the correct proportions of your background image. Then it all adjusts nicely when you resize the browser.